# expect script not returning a value to bash script

Tags: shell

Please help me to solve this.

I have written a bash script as given below. My goal is to get a return value from the expect script which included with bash script.

The script which i made is as given below.

> #!/bin/bash
>   x=$(expect -c '
>   spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@10.3.2.0
>   expect "*d: "
>
>   send "qbcrootpass\r"
>
>   expect "*#"
>   send "res=hello\r"
>   send "\$res\r"
>   interact
>   ')
>   echo $x

But it is not working as I expected !! :(

What modification i need to do ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the exit status of the most recently exited foreground pipeline, you should use the [`$?` special parameter](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters):

```
#!/bin/bash
x=$(expect ...)
y=$?
# $x now contains the output from the 'expect' command, and $y contains the
# exit status
```

Comment: But when I echo $x it does not giving any output. Actually the script hangs when i run it.